# Динамическое добавление popup элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как в semantic ui динамически добавить энное количество popup элементов, чтобы у каждого имелся атрибут с уникальным контентом data-html="Уникальный контент".

Проблема заключается в том, что semantic ui когда видит подобный атрибут при загрузке страницы создает соответствующий ему div, а при динамическом создании элемента с данным атрибутом он не создает нужный div. Но даже если явно указывать какой элемент отобразить (по id), то ничего не происходит и не отображается.

Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нашел решение.

```
$('Нужные элементы').popup('refresh');
```